# Given monthly mean, STD and median, how do I calculate the weekly mean, STD and median?

Tags: statistics

Given a dataset like this:

```
    Month   Total Sales
Jan_2013        100
Feb_2013        350
Mar_2013        500
```

I have calculated the monthly mean 316.67 (=(100+350+500)/3), STDEV 202.07 and median 350.

Now I want, the weekly mean, STDEV and median. My immediate thought was to just divide the numbers by 4, but now I am not so sure, it seems "too easy", but then again, I don't really see any alternative. Would be awesome if some of you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can't, that information is lost once you add the numbers together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate any of the desired statistics from the monthly statistics. To see this, notice that for any fixed choice of monthly stats, there is a way to assign weekly sales such that the first week has no sales, but also a way to assign it so that the first week has all of the sales.